# Extension method with generic parameter called from subclass instance

Tags: c#, generics

Here is my issue:

```cs
public class User
{
    public virtual void Save()
    {
        Connection.Save(this);
    }
}

public class Administrator : User
{
}

public static class Queries
{
    public static void Save<T>(this IDbConnection cn, T entity)
    {
        var properties = Mapper<T>.GetProperties();
        // other code
    }
}

public static class Mapper<T>
{
    public static IList<Property> GetProperties()
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        // other code
    }

    // other T-dependent methods
}
```

When `user.Save()` is called, it works fine, however for `admin.Save()` the generic parameter `T` is `User`, not `Administrator`, so reflection inside `GetProperties()` returns user properties.

I can make it work by overloading `Mapper<T>.GetProperties(instance.GetType())`, but this seems not semantically correct, as having two types leads to ambiguity.

Is there a better way to resolve the issue? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the the parts that use Save method and Mapper type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generic type arguments are resolved at compile time, not at runtime, there's nothing that can be done about that.
You need to determine the type by using `GetType()` on an instance of the object to get the runtime type, so you might have to rethink your design a bit keeping that in mind. Maybe using generics isn't the best thing to do in this case.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, there are too much code written to revamp the Mapper class. I had to resort to changing User's `virtual void Save()` to `static void Save<T>(T user) where T : User`. This way both `User.Save(user)` and `User.Save(admin)` work.

Comment: @HermanKan but if you do  
`User user = admin;    
User.Save(user);  `
then it would stop working.